# Finding other two vertices when one vertex and each point on the triangle is known ?

Tags: algorithms, triangles, computational-geometry

I am working on some gesture recognition for my game. I am stuck on a problem. I have one vertex i.e **the starting point and every point on the triangle, I also have the centroid. So how do I find the other two vertices based on this info** .

I have previously asked a similar question but i did not mention that I have all the points on the triangle.

Comment: To clarify, is this in 2-d or 3-d?

Comment: its a 2-d triangle....

Comment: You mean a triangle embedded in 2-d space?  (Triangles are 2-d by definition.)  I don't know in what sense you know every point in the triangle, but the other vertices will have extremal $x$ and/or $y$ values, so you could find those if it's feasible.  The centroid won't help too much unless you know a second vertex (all it will tell you with 1 vertex are bounds on where the other vertices lie).